# "Not Charging" after battery replacement

Tags: power-management, battery

So, I replaced the old battery in my Acer Aspire laptop with a new one.

And it doesn't charge.

[image]

[image]

It was like this, at 0%, when I first turned on the laptop, even though I could use the laptop for like a half hour, without the charger plugged in. (Funny thing though, on windows, it said, that the battery was at 100%). Then I had the charger plugged for like 3 hours, but it definitely didn't and doesn't charge the battery; now if the charger is not plugged, the laptop shuts down in less than a minute.

This is the output of `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1`:

```
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               UNKNOWN
  model:                UNKNOWN
  serial:               0
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              2024. jan. 13., szombat, 21:22:44 CET (26 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               pending-charge
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              0 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         0 Wh
    energy-full-design:  0 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    charge-cycles:       N/A
    percentage:          0%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-charging-symbolic'
```

Could anyone help what might be the problem here? Could I have messed something up, when I put in the new battery?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you still have the old battery?

Comment: A battery is fully hardware operated. the OS only asks the bios for intel on it.   My  opinion: the battery is broken :P

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yes.

Comment: @Rinzwind Really? I just bought it.

Comment: I doubt you have 2 machines for this battery to check yourself :)  But I would go back to the place you bought it from and let them proof it is working. You could have a bigger issue: a broken connector.

Comment: Or maybe a faulty battery or compatibility issues...